# systemjs.config.js not appending *.js to file names

Tags: angular, systemjs

I get a 404 Not Found in the Chrome developer console for the app.module.js because the URL trying to be resolved, after first typing in the URL to index.html, is like this, **notice the app.module is missing the .js extension**:

http://localhost:8080/someTomcatContext/scripts/someAppName/src/app/app.module

Here is the folder structure:

```
node_modules
package.json
styles.css
systemjs.config.extras.js
systemjs.config.js
systemjs-angular-loader.js
tslint.json
src
|-- app
|   |-- app.component.ts
|   |-- app.module.ts
|   |-- app.routes.ts
|-- index.html
|-- main.ts
|-- tsconfig.json
```

I have the following system.config.js

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': '../node_modules/'
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  'app': 'src/app',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    meta: {
      './*.js': {
        loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
      }
    }
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
 });
})(this);
```

I have tried changing the wildcard with the following two variations in order to append the .js extension inside the system.config.js shown above:

```
  './src/app/*.js'
  './app/*.js'
```

Here is the contents of the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
</script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="../systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my Angular 2 application to an Angular 4 application, and I used the quickstart project (https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git) as a skeleton.

I placed my application specific TS files in the src/app folder and got this working with the following structure:

```
node_modules
package.json
tslint.json
src
|-- app
|   |-- app.component.ts
|   |-- app.module.ts
|   |-- app.routes.ts
|-- index.html
|-- main.ts
|-- styles.css
|-- systemjs.config.extras.js
|-- systemjs.config.js
|-- systemjs-angular-loader.js
|-- tsconfig.json
```

My systemjs.config.js looks like this:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '../node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

And my index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

The main.ts looks like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this may be coming in too late, but I hope it helps someone else. I experienced the same issue with the angular quickstart project. Turns out you need to add a `defaultJSExtensions` flag to System.config in systemjs.config.js file, and set that to true like so.

```
System.config(
    //paths and other settings...
    defaultJSExtensions : true
)(this);
```

See issue on github https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/812